# Solve matrix equation $XAX^*=B$ for $X$ in least squares sense

Tags: matrices, optimization, matrix-equations, least-squares, symmetry

How can the following optimization problem be solved?

$$\arg\min_{\mathbf{X} \in \mathcal{C}^{n \times m}} \left\Vert \mathbf{X}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}^* - \mathbf{B} \right\Vert_F$$

where $\mathbf{A} \in \mathcal{C}^{m \times m}$ and $\mathbf{B} \in \mathcal{C}^{n \times n}$ are Hermitian, with $m > n$, generally. Matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is diagonal and invertible. Let $^*$ denote the conjugate transpose.

---

### Solution attempt

Solution attempt was wrong, see comments. See the answers for a better attempt.

<s>I realize it is possible to take the derivative of the expression and equating it to zero, but I end up with the following expression I have trouble with</s>

$\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}{\frac{d}{d \mathbf{X}}\mathrm{Tr}\left( \mathbf{X}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}^* \mathbf{X}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}^* - 2\mathbf{X}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}^*\mathbf{B} + \mathbf{B}^*\mathbf{B} \right) = 0}$

$\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}{\mathbf{X}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}^* \mathbf{X}\mathbf{A} - \mathbf{B}\mathbf{X}\mathbf{A} = 0}$

Because $\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}{\mathbf{A}}$ is invertible

$\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}{\mathbf{X}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}^*\mathbf{X} - \mathbf{B}\mathbf{X} = 0}$

Which does not seem any simpler.

### Variant

Would the following variant be harder to solve? I don't see it working with Måren W's answer below

$\underset{\mathbf{X}}{\mathrm{argmin}} \left\Vert \mathbf{X}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}^T - \mathbf{B} \right\Vert_F$

with $m > n$. Again the matrices are complex, but now $\mathbf{A}$ is a symmetric (not Hermitian), diagonal and invertible matrix and $\mathbf{B}$ is also symmetric.

Comment: Does $X^*$ denotes the conjugate transpose of $X$ or just the transpose?

Comment: I missed that, it should be the conjugate transpose.

Comment: C should have been A, fixed. Thanks

Comment: In your solution attempt, $\textbf{XA}$ does not necessarily have an inverse just because $\textbf{XA}\neq 0$..

Comment: I was not assuming it could be inverted, just that $(\mathbf{X}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}^* - \mathbf{B})\mathbf{X}\mathbf{A} = 0$, which is interesting only if $\mathbf{X}\mathbf{A} \neq 0$.

Comment: @zilver: When you go from $(\mathbf{XAX}^*-\mathbf{B})\mathbf{XA}=0$ to $\mathbf{XAX}^*-\mathbf{B}=0$ you must assume that $\mathbf{XA}$ in invertible. The condition $\mathbf{XA}\neq0$ is _not_ sufficient.

Comment: Right, and $\mathrm{X}\mathrm{A}$ is not invertible as it is not necessarily squared, so then I'm stuck with the larger expression.

Comment: Mårten W: But does it not hold because $\mathbf{A}$ is invertible and we look for the non-trivial solution for $\mathbf{X}$?

Comment: @zilver: No, when working with matrices you may have zero-divisors. If $\mathbf{A}$ is invertible, then you can go to $(\mathbf{XAX}^*-\mathbf{B})\mathbf{X}=\mathbf{0}$, but you cannot conclude that one of the factors must be zero.

Comment: zilver, that you wrote is false. The derivative of $X^*$ wrt $x_{i,j}$ does not exist. Moreover, in your formula giving the trace, you assume that $A$ is hermitian, that is a supplementary non-written condition.

Comment: That was a (possibly incorrect) solution attempt. You are right about $\mathbf{A}$. I will update the problem. However, I don't follow about the derivative of $\mathbf{X}^*$ wrt to $x_{i,j}$.

Comment: zilver, $\overline{z}$ has no derivative wrt $z$ my friend. Consider the case when the matrices are real.

Comment: Use `\arg\min`. I would square all Frobenius norms. Squaring the Frobenius norm, the objective is quadratic. Finding where the gradient vanishes, we obtain a cubic matrix equation.

Answer (score 4):

For the special case where $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are positive definite ($\mathbf{B}$ can be positive semidefinite), we may do as follows:

Let $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{U}_1\mathbf{\Sigma}_1\mathbf{U}_1^*$ be a singular value decomposition of $\mathbf{A}$, and let $\tilde{\mathbf{B}}=\mathbf{U}_2\mathbf{\Sigma}_2\mathbf{U}_2^*$ be a singular value decomposition of the zero padded matrix
$$
\tilde{\mathbf{B}} =
\begin{bmatrix}
    \mathbf{B} & \mathbf{0} \\
    \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0}
\end{bmatrix}
\in\mathcal{C}^{m\times m}.
$$
Then
$$
\lVert\tilde{\mathbf{X}}\mathbf{A}\tilde{\mathbf{X}}^*-\tilde{\mathbf{B}}\rVert_F =
\lVert\tilde{\mathbf{X}}\mathbf{U}_1\mathbf{\Sigma}_1\mathbf{U}_1^*\tilde{\mathbf{X}}^*-\mathbf{U}_2\mathbf{\Sigma}_2\mathbf{U}_2^*\rVert_F =
\lVert\mathbf{U}_2^*\tilde{\mathbf{X}}\mathbf{U}_1\mathbf{\Sigma}_1\mathbf{U}_1^*\tilde{\mathbf{X}}^*\mathbf{U}_2-\mathbf{\Sigma}_2\rVert_F.
$$
This is zero (and thus minimal) if
$\mathbf{U}_2^*\tilde{\mathbf{X}}\mathbf{U}_1\sqrt{\mathbf{\Sigma}_1}=\sqrt{\mathbf{\Sigma}_2}$, i.e. when
$$
\tilde{\mathbf{X}}=\mathbf{U}_2\sqrt{\mathbf{\Sigma}_2\mathbf{\Sigma}_1^{-1}}\mathbf{U}_1^*.
$$
Now, if $\mathbf{X}$ is the topmost $n\times m$ submatrix of $\tilde{\mathbf{X}}$, then
$$
\lVert\mathbf{X}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}^*-\mathbf{B}\rVert_F = 0.
$$

Comment: You diagonalize $A,B$; then $\Sigma_i$ is not necessarily $>0$.

Comment: @loupblanc: Oh, I had completely forgotten about this unfinished answer. Yes, it seems that I must have made an additional assumption that $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are positive definite. Unfortunately I need that in the last step where I do the Cholesky decomposition.. I'll edit and add this assumption.

Answer (score 1):

I write some remarks.

I see that the OP did not remove his false derivative...

Remark 1. Let $si(A)=(p+,q-)$ be the signature of $A$. Then the signature of $XAX^*$ has the form $si(B)=(u+,v-,w0)$ where $u\leq p,v\leq q$. In particular, if $A> 0$, then $XAX^*\geq 0$.

Then, in general, there is no $X$ st $XAX^*=B$.

Remark 2. We may assume that $B$ is a diagonal real matrix. (cf. the Marten's calculation).

Remark 3. If $A>0,B\leq 0$ then $\inf||XAX^*-B||=||B||$.

Indeed, $||XAX^*-B||^2=tr((R+S)^2)$ where $R=XAX^*\geq0,S=-B\geq 0$. Clearly $tr((R+S)^2)\geq tr(S^2)=||B||^2$.

Remark 4. If $si(B)=(u+,v-,w0)$ with $u\leq p,v\leq q$, then there is $X$ st $XAX^*=B$.

Indeed, since a permutation is orthogonal, we may assume $A=diag(U_{u},V_{v},W_{m-u-v})$ where $U,V,W$ are diagonal, $U>0,V<0$ and $B=diag(P_u,Q_v,0_{n-u-v})$ where $P,Q$ are diagonal and $P>0,Q<0$. There is

$Y\in  GL_{u+v}$ st $Ydiag(U,V)Y^*=diag(P,Q)$.

Then $X=\begin{pmatrix}Y&0_{u+v,m-u-v}\\0_{w,u+v}&0_{w,m-u-v}\end{pmatrix}$ is a required solution.

EDIT. Some toy examples seem to show that the following conjecture is true (but I am not sure).

$\textbf{Conjecture}$. The lower bound of $||XAX^*-B||$ is reached for some $X$ st $XAX^*$ is diagonal.

If this is true, then we are done, as shows the following example

$si(A)=(2+,2-)$ and $B=diag(a,2,1)$ where $a\geq0$.

If $a>1$, then a best approximation is $diag(a,2,0)$.

If $a=1$, then two best approx are $diag(1,2,0),diag(0,2,1)$.

If $a<1$, then a best approx is $diag(0,2,1)$.